# Angular e2e tests not working

Tags: angular, e2e-testing

The ng e2e is not working behind the proxy/firewall so installed protractor globally and then updated the webdriver-manager update (with proxy) and then copied the output into my project. 
After that I ran the command ng e2e and i get the following error:

```
webpack: Compiled successfully.
[11:19:15] I/update - chromedriver: file exists C:\Dev\deviceprofiler\ui\node_modules\protractor\node_modules\webdriver-manager\seleniu
m\chromedriver_2.33.zip
[11:19:15] I/update - chromedriver: unzipping chromedriver_2.33.zip
[11:19:15] I/update - chromedriver: chromedriver_2.33.exe up to date
[11:19:16] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver
[11:19:16] I/direct - Using ChromeDriver directly...
Jasmine started
[11:19:31] E/protractor - Could not find Angular on page http://localhost:49152/ : retries looking for angular exceeded
```

What's the issue and how can I run the ng e2e tests behind proxy. Are there any steps I need to follow?

Comment: "Not working" is not a technical term.

Comment: @Rob I am not sure what you mean? I don't know what the issue is Could not find Angular on page http://localhost:49152/... The app cleary loads in browser with this url and then i get this error. Not sure how else I can say it.

Answer (score 0):

This means Protractor is not able to find `"Angular"` in your web page. If your application is a non-angular application or if Protractor couldn't find Angular in page within a pre-defined time period, then this error is thrown.

Depending on the conditions, you need to either increase the timeout period (most likely due to a proxy) or configure Protractor to not wait for Protractor.

Both of these have been discussed [here](https://github.com/angular/protractor/blob/master/docs/timeouts.md#waiting-for-angular-on-page-load).

You can config Protractor to not wait for Angular using

- `browser.waitForAngularEnabled(false)`
- `browser.ignoreSynchronization = true`

I would prefer the later one for doing the same.

Comment: I did increase the timeout period but i get the same error.

Comment: did you try disabling to wait for Angular?

Comment: how do i do that in angular cli ?

Comment: Could you find your app directly by browser just trying http://localhost:49152/?
I get the same message if the app is not served, e.g. ng serve is not running.